# memory exception using wcf wshttpbinding

Tags: wcf, exception, memory, wshttpbinding

I have an application to upload files to a server. I am using nettcpbinding and wshttpbinding. When the files is larger than 200 MB, I get a memory exception. Working around this, I have seen people recommend streaming, and of course it works with nettcpbinding for large files (>1GB), but when using wshttpbinding, what would be the approach?? Should I change to basichttpbinding?? what?? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you expose another end point just to upload such large size data. This can have a binding that supports streaming. In our previous project we needed to do file uploads to server as part of business process. We ended up creating 2 endpoints one just dedicated to file upload, and another for all other business functionality.
The streaming data service can be a generic service to stream any data to the server and maybe return a token for identifying the data on server.For subsequent requests this token can be passed along to manipulate the data on server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to (or cannot because of legit reasons) change the binding nor use streaming, what you can do is have some method with a signature along the lines of the following:

```
void UploadFile(string fileName, long offset, byte[] data)
```

Instead of sending the whole file, you send little packets, and tell where the data should be placed. You can add more data, of course, like the whole filesize, CRC of the file to know if the transfer was successful, etc.